# AWS - Get Activation Key for Storage Gateway From Lambda

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, command-line, aws-lambda

I am trying to write a bit of automation that will get the activation key from the instance and activate a storage gateway on AWS. I have been writing this in AWS Lambda for python 3.6 using the "requests" library only to be hit with:

```
Your web browser must have JavaScript enabled
```

Error whenever I do a get request. However on their docs:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/latest/userguide/get-activation-key.html#get-activation-key-cli

They use wget to make the request to the instance and get a response back with the activation key. Wget doesn't have a javascript interpreter, how is that even working?

Is this possible through straight python or am I stuck with downloading a fat binary like selenium or phantomjs, extracting it into a zip, and uploading that zip just to make a web request with javascript in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curl is installed on lambdas. I was able to achieve this with curl.

```
def get_gateway_activation_key(event):
  print("Getting activation key...")
  fgs = event["ResourceProperties"]["FileGatewayOptions"]["FileGatewaySettings"]
  url = "redirect_url=$(curl -f -s -S -w '%%{redirect_url}' \"http://%s/?activationRegion=%s\")  && echo $redirect_url" % (fgs["InstanceIP"],fgs["GatewayRegion"])
  redirect_url = os.popen(url).read()
  if redirect_url == "" or redirect_url is None:
      raise Exception("No redirect url returned for ip: %s" % fgs["InstanceIP"])
  key = redirect_url.split("activationKey=")[1].split("&gateway")[0]
  if key is None or key is "":
      raise Exception("Unable to extract the key from the returned redirect url: %s" %redirect_url)
  print("Retrieved Activation Key: %s" % key)
  return key
```